# Restlet routing - Route being overtaken by another route

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

I've come up to a strange routing problem in restlet. I'm using android.

This class `extends Router`

This is my routing code:

```
    this.attach("/contacts", contactListRestlet); // To list all contacts
    this.attach("/contacts/{uid}", contactRestlet); // To show details about a specific contact
    this.attach("/contacts/similar", similarRestlet, Template.MODE_EQUALS);
    this.attach("/contact/photo/{uid}", photoRestlet); // {uid} must correspond to a valid raw contact id
    this.attach("/contact/photo/{uid}/thumbnail", photoThumbnailRestlet);
    this.attach("/import/file", fileImportRestlet);
    this.attach("/echo", echoRestlet);
    this.attach("/echo/file", echoFileRestlet);
    this.attach("/import/vcard", importVcard);
    this.attach("/logout", logoutRestlet);

    final String ROOT_URI = "file:///android_asset";
    Application application = new Application() {  
        @Override  
        public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
            //ForAssets
            DirectoryForAssets d = new DirectoryForAssets(getContext(), ROOT_URI);
            d.setTargetClass(DirectoryResourceExtension.class);
            d.setAndroidContext(context);
            return d;  
        }  
    };
    this.attach("/editor", application, Template.MODE_STARTS_WITH);
```

this way if I hit `ip:port/contacts/similar` I always get redirected to `/contacts restlet` (`contactRestlet`) and not to `/contacts/similar restlet` (`similarRestlet`) as I was expecting.

But if I change it to:

```
    this.attach("/contacts/similar", similarRestlet);
    this.attach("/contacts", contactListRestlet); // To list all contacts
    this.attach("/contacts/{uid}", contactRestlet); // To show details about a specific contact
    this.attach("/contact/photo/{uid}", photoRestlet); // {uid} must correspond to a valid raw contact id
    this.attach("/contact/photo/{uid}/thumbnail", photoThumbnailRestlet);
    this.attach("/import/file", fileImportRestlet);
    this.attach("/echo", echoRestlet);
    this.attach("/echo/file", echoFileRestlet);
    this.attach("/import/vcard", importVcard);
    this.attach("/logout", logoutRestlet);

    final String ROOT_URI = "file:///android_asset";
    Application application = new Application() {  
        @Override  
        public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
            //ForAssets
            DirectoryForAssets d = new DirectoryForAssets(getContext(), ROOT_URI);
            d.setTargetClass(DirectoryResourceExtension.class);
            d.setAndroidContext(context);
            return d;  
        }  
    };
    this.attach("/editor", application, Template.MODE_STARTS_WITH);
```

it does work! (The only difference is similarRestlet comes first than contactRestlet).

Can anyone explain me why this behaviour? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the Router matches the first available match, other matching modes including best match exist.  This can be adjusted by changing `setDefaultMatchingMode(int)`  See restlet JavaDoc for additional information. Currently at http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.3/jse/api/org/restlet/routing/Router.html

Answer (score 1):

```
"/contacts/{uid}"
"/contacts/similar"
```

If you have this above sequence, it will use the {uid} and fill in "similar" this is because it cannot distinguish the both, and uses "similar" as a "uid".

So when you put it like this:

```
"/contacts/similar"
"/contacts/{uid}"
```

It first catches "similar", and if it is not "similar", it will use that part as a uid.

Comment: Bert's answer is correct for the First available match matching mode (default).